# AWS API Gateway "x-amzn-requestid" - Can it be captured inside .net core

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, asp.net-core, aws-api-gateway, correlation

Is there a way to capture AWS API Gateway "x-amzn-requestid" inside .Net Core API Exception filter method?

Comment: You may need to expand your question to clarify where your code is, in relation to API Gateway.  Is your code making calls to an API Gateway API, or is your code being invoked (Lambda) by API Gateway?  I suspect the former, but initially assumed the latter.

Comment: My code is being invoked by API Gateway, I want to capture the request id generated by API Gateway in aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Scratch what I said below just use this example->
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents

You will see the headers there

`var headerNames = string.Join(", ", apigProxyEvent.Headers.Keys);`

Comment: How I found the answer.

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer/APIGatewayProxyFunction.cs#L225